# Supressing system("command") console window in a window application with MINGW

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw

I have a WINMAIN application say hello world.

i used

```
-mwindows
```

switch option in linker to make sure it does GUI application.
But when i execute some system commands like

```
system("dir");
```

from the C code it pops out a console.

Is there a option to supress the console window??

Please guide. Below is the hello world code using Mingw GCC

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI
WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
  MessageBoxW (NULL, L"Hello World!", L"hello", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  system("dir");
  system("dir");
  system("dir");
  system("dir");
  Sleep(1000);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use CreateProcess and hide the window.

Comment: @RetiredNinja :: i am very to windows GUI apps can you get a reference for the same.

Comment: Don't use system.  If you want to list the files in a directory, check out this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `dir`, but dir is not a program like `ls` in Unix. It is a command.

So to execute `dir`, a `CMD.exe` has to be spawn, hence the console window.

Use [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as suggested by @carl to list files in a directory.